# I need to identify characters in a string using a users input

Tags: charat

For example if the user enters the string "hello world" they will then be prompted for a number. If the user enters "6" I want "w" to print

This is my work so far which doesn't seem to work

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a string:");

    String str = in.next();

    System.out.print("Enter the index: ");

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    char c = reader.next().charAt(0);

    System.out.print(c);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code. You have to use nextLine rather than next

```
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class Test {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.print("Enter a string:");


       String str = in.nextLine();

       System.out.print("Enter the index: ");


       Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

       Integer index = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
       char c = str.charAt(index);

       System.out.print(c);
       }}
```